# Неправильно работает margin-top

Tags: вёрстка

Между `header` и верхним краем браузера есть пробел который я не ожидал увидеть, а также не работает даже позиционирование `top` у элемента `.company`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.general {
  height: 6200px;
}

.company {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 560px;
  margin-left: 12%;
  color: white;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 12.7%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>page1</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="general">
    <header>
      <div class="company">mycompany</div>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: а с чего вдруг мысль, что тут в примере, что-то не работает? Все идеально, как стили прописаны так и работает...  Свойство `top, right, bottom, left` без `position: absolute | reative | fixed;` работать и не должны

Comment: Что бы получить ответ внятный, надо нормально задать вопрос, как минимум объяснить, что не работает и конечный желаемый результат....

Comment: @Air опубликуйте Ваш первый комментарий как ответ

Comment: Можно и самому ответить на свой вопрос... )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Между `header` и верхним краем браузера есть пробел который я не
>   ожидал увидеть

Это ожидаемо, так как этот пробел создается установленным для элемента `company` свойством `margin-top: 560px;`

> а также не работает даже позиционирование `top` у элемента `.company`

Чтобы работало свойство `top` для элемента `.company`, необходимо этому элементу установить значение свойства `position`. Вероятнее всего, вы планируете определить расстояние от верхнего края родительского элемента `general` до верхнего края дочернего элемента `.company`. Предположим, что это так. Значит для элемента `general` нужно задать `position: relative`.

Теперь внесем все эти изменения в Ваш код:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.general {
  height: 6200px;
}

.company {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  /*margin-top: 560px; Удаляем*/
  margin-left: 12%;
  color: white;
  position: relative; /*Добавляем*/
  top: 12%; /*Добавляем*/
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 12.7%;
}
```

```html
<div class="general">
  <header>
    <div class="company">mycompany</div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Какой можно сделать из этого вывод?

> ## Неправильно работает margin-top

В приведенном Вами вопросе код работает совершенно верно, согласно заданому Вами стилю. Вопрос в том, что Вы получили то, что получили, а не то, что планировали получить в результате. Ответ: `margin-top` работает правильно.

*Чтобы таблицы стилей корректно работали, необходимо знать CSS синтаксис, набор правил при описании стиля, который описывает форматирование (изменение внешнего вида) отдельно взятых элементов на веб-странице.*

Answer (score 0):

Есть некоторые параметры отображения у браузера по-умолчанию, чтобы их убрать см:
https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/boost/frontend/about-normalize-css
https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: это не помогло, я даже не знаю, подключив normalize через npm, как далее его подключить и использовать при верстке

Comment: https://www.kobzarev.com/makeup/normalization-of-css-with-normalize-css/#kak-ispolzovat

Comment: не работает, подключил в HTML `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">`, но это не сработало